# How to install Aurelia UX 0.4.0 with Aurelia CLI?

Tags: npm, aurelia

I’ve been using `aurelia-ux 0.3.0` for some time now and love the concept. Since the move to `aurelia-ux 0.4.0` and the shift to monorepo I’m a little lost on how to install and use the library.

Could anyone provide a little exemple on how to install `aurelia-ux 0.4.0` (core + 1-2 components) with aurelia-cli ?

Notice: the current npm documentation of [@aurelia-ux/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aurelia-ux/core) package points to the [showcase application](https://github.com/aurelia/app-ux-showcase) - however this showcase still runs 0.3.0.

Comment: I agree, the documentation on this totally sucks. I can't get 0.6.1 to work either.

Comment: @Flores You're right. However I've been able to make it work and below is my answer to help you. Hope you can make it work as well and enjoy this great plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests and research I've been able to install `auralia-ux 0.4.0+`

**First you need to install the core and components**

```
npm install @aurelia-ux/core
```

Then you can either install each component separately or together

```
npm install @aurelia-ux/button
npm install @aurelia-ux/input
npm install @aurelia-ux/...

# or

npm install @aurelia-ux/components
```

**Then in the `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` you need to add the dependencies as such:**

```
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/core",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/core/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/button",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/button/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/input",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/input/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
  "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
```

or if you prefer the `components` variant (warning: I haven't tested this variant):

```
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/core",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/core/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "@aurelia-ux/components",
  "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "**/*.{css,html}"
  ]
}
```

**Finaly you must register the plugins in your main.js**

```
aurelia.use
.plugin('@aurelia-ux/core')
.plugin('@aurelia-ux/button')
.plugin('@aurelia-ux/input')
```

or with the components variant (not tested)

```
aurelia.use
.plugin('@aurelia-ux/core')
.plugin('@aurelia-ux/components')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful. I've tried the components part, but can't get that to work. Individual components work with the method above, also for version 0.6.1